# How to Create a List of Type<T1, T2> where T1 & T2 can contain multiple types?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

This question involves Task Parallel Library DataFlow.

Consider this statement:

```
var sampleBlock = new TransformBlock<XDocument, string>
    (xml => TransformXmlToString.Transform(xml));
```

I want to maintain a list of `TransformBlock` but the Func transform parameter (`TransformXmlToString.Transform(xml)`) has me stuck. I can illustrate what I want with the following pseudo-code:

```
var listOfTransformBlocks = new List<TransformBlock>
{
    new TransformBlock<T1, T2>(t1 => SomeTransformClass.SomeMethod),
    new TransformBlock<T2, T3>(t2 => SomeOtherTransformClass.SomeMethod),
    new TransformBlock<T3, T4>(t3 => YetOtherTransformClass.SomeMethod)
};
```

How can I achieve the ability to maintain a list of `TransformBlock` in a way that I will be able to retrieve, link and use (I'd want a similar thing for `ActionBlock` as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have list of items with unrelated types (note that in case of `class F<T>{}` `Foo<One>` and `Foo<Other>` are not related to each other since there is no common parent).

Since `IDataflowBlock` is only shared base class/interface for your types you have to do:

```
var listOfTransformBlocks = new List<IDataflowBlock> {...}
```

Unfortunately you'll lose compile-time ability to find types of your transformation and have to write some run-time code to find them back.